# Zend File Create folder while uploading

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

With this form element I'm uploading a file:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_File('foo');
$element->setLabel('Upload Image1:')
        ->setDestination('/var/www/upload');

$element->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
$element->addValidator('Size', false, 102400);
$element->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif');
$form->addElement($element, 'foo');
```

This requires that the folder is already existing.
How can I add an option, that the folder is beeing created, but only if a user selects a file and the upload succeeds?

Comment: The issue here is that the user PHP is running as will need to have write permission to more than just `/var/www/upload`, it'll need write privileges to `/var/www`, which, I assume, is your web root. In theory this opens up a big security hole. You should consider something a bit more focused. Either that or, if you have a deploy script (composer?) for your application, have the deploy operation create the directory with limited permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to remove `->setDestination` from your form and put it in your controller.

The following is what you will put in your controller.

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
if (//code to check if folder '/var/www/upload' does not exist)
{
//code to create a folder '/var/www/upload' and then set destination to that folder
$upload->setDestination('/var/www/upload');
}
```

Comment: Is this going to be runned if there is no file selected? As described, I want to create the folder only if there is at least one selected file.

Comment: You can do something like  this to check if the file or files were uploaded. $files = $upload->getFileInfo(); foreach ($files as $file => $info) {
    // file uploaded ?
    if (!$upload->isUploaded($file)) { }

Comment: Refer to the manual http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.html. The manual for Zend 2 will be different

Comment: As told earlier, you first need to go through the documentation for the complete procedure of file upload. Anyhow $upload->receive(); method is used to receive the file in the controller.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300117/zend-file-upload-does-not-work this is my current problem.

Comment: There is no question, at the above link. Try to debug your files with this code $files = $upload->getFileInfo();
             var_dump($files);

Comment: if(!$upload->receive($info['name'])) {
                    $msg= $upload->getMessages();
                    echo 'error is ';var_dump($msg);
                    }

Comment: Use these two codes to check where the file code is failing.